# any efficient way to find surrounding adjective/verbs with respect to the target phrase in python [updated]?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis on given documents. My goal is to find out the closest or surrounding **adjective words with respect to the target phrase** in my sentences. I do have an idea how to extract surrounding words with respect to target phrases. But how do I find out **relatively close or closest** adjective or `NNP` or `VBN` or other POS tag with respect to target phrase ?

Here is the sketch idea of how I may get surrounding words with respect to my target phrase.

```
sentence_List = {
    "Obviously one of the most important features of any computer is the human interface.", 
    "Good for everyday computing and web browsing.",
    "My problem was with DELL Customer Service", 
    "I play a lot of casual games online[comma] and the touchpad is very responsive"
}

target_phraseList = {
    "human interface",
    "everyday computing",
    "DELL Customer Service",
    "touchpad"
}
```

Note that my original dataset was given as DataFrame where the list of the sentences and respective target phrases were given. Here I just simulated data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.Series(sentence_List, target_phraseList)
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Here, I tokenize the sentence as follow:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in sentence_List]
tokenized=[i for i in tokenized_sents]
```

Then I try to find out surrounding words with respect to my target phrases by using this [loot at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645701/extract-words-surrounding-a-search-word). However, I want to find out relatively closer or closest `adjective`, or `verbs` or `VBN` with respect to my target phrase.

How can I make this happen? Any idea to get this done? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at spacy, they have models already trained to POS tag a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**POS-tagging** consist of qualifying words by attaching a Part-Of-Speech to it. Part-Of-Speech is a tag that indicates the **role of a word in a sentence** (e.g. a noun, a transitive verb, a comparative adjective, etc.). You need this to know if a word is an adjective, and it is easily done with the *nltk* package you are using [[source]](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html):

```
>> nltk.pos_tag("The grand jury")
>> ('The', 'AT'), ('grand', 'JJ'), ('jury', 'NN')
```

Here, JJ means "Adjective" and "NN" means "Common Noun".

In your case, you are interested in neighbors adjectives. Does that mean "the closest adjective" in the sentence ? Or adjectives within a radius of the target, if any?
Depending on the definition, the way to do it differs.

For **adjectives within a radius**, as you have already selected words within a radius using the [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645701/extract-words-surrounding-a-search-word) you mentioned, you can POS-tag them and then select only those with a tag that indicates an adjective tag.

```
>> adjective_tags = ["JJ", "JJR", "JJS"]
>> close_adjectives_list = [a[0] for a in nltk.pos_tag(" ".join(close_words_list)) if a[1] in adjective_tags ]
```

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38264311/8086033) that list most of existing POS-tags.